# service startup issue, how to properly trap errors

Tags: windows-services, reporting, startup

In 2008/2008 R2 there are alot of security settings. Restrictions to file access even eventlog ..

Often I see that when I'm coding locally or on our dev servers our services run smootly, but when shifting them to a production envirnoment, and our services fails to start, it takes alot of time to track down what the issue is.

Since both fileacess and even the eventlog may be configured so that both are off limits.
What should one do in such cases?

Troubleshooting when you have no output from the service at all.
Particulary when you have a 3rd party that is to install and maintain your services? Write an app that verifies access to all resources used by the service?

So the following may be configured in a way that they are off limits:

EventLog,
Custom disk logging,
Console.

Which leaves us with what option?

I hear the next version of windows server, w2k14 has even stricter security policies. 
When you try to boot a computer with it installed it prompts you the following at startup, 
"Having your computer turned on my harm it. " Then it shuts down ;)

Brgds,
Stian

Comment: C#, but these restrictions are from the OS, so any direct w32 api call would result in the same restrictions. Sort of solved my issue by making a parameter, that would start my service as an application so I could get some output atleast.

Comment: You can view all access events using the tool [Promom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that file system access can be completly turned off, so writing to "public" resources should still be allowed (for example C:\ProgramData, C:\Users\Public), in the worst case, you can create a simple service that query all the other services, actually, i did that once with a service on Linux (via Network sockets), that basically was a bootstrap service that allowed me to control the main service in a rustic command line.

Comment: Ty for your response. Solved my issue as described in the comment above.